# Which of these class level attributes generated by using XSD.exe can be discarded safely?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, xml-deserialization, xsd.exe

I used <kbd>XSD.exe</kbd> against an XML schema file (`.XSD`) to generate C# classes for use in deserializing XML data files that conform to the said XML schema.

I noticed the following class level attributes have been added to all the generated classes.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
```

In some cases, the tool has also generated the `XmlElementAttribute` attribute, which I am well aware is necessary for proper deserialization.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Field")]
```

So other than this `XmlElementAttribute`, which of the aforementioned attributes are really required for deserialization to be successful. I know I can remove them 1 by 1 and try it out, but there are a lot of classes and I want to keep my class definitions as 'clean' as possible without having un-necessary attributes all over the place.

Here's a sample class definition generated by <kbd>XSD.exe</kbd>, in case you need to look at the class also.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class CrystalReportReportFooter {

    private CrystalReportReportFooterSection sectionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public CrystalReportReportFooterSection Section {
        get {
            return this.sectionField;
        }
        set {
            this.sectionField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be safe to remove unless the tool that regenerates the code needs this.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
```

---

You need this as this is what tells a class that it can be serialized.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
```

---

This can be removed. It's purely for debugging and may end up hindering debugging later on if you add custom code.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
```

---

This can be removed. Only used for the IDE or any WYSIWYG designer that takes advantage of it.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
```

---

This is up to you. Basically it is telling the Serializer that the class is an anonymous XSD type.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
```